# Why is tf.io.read_file not able to read from pathlib.Path object?

Tags: tensorflow, pathlib

I have an image path:

```
file_path = '/dir/sub_dir/my_image.jpg'
```

These both work fine:

```
open(file_path, 'r')
tensorflow.io.read_file(file_path)
```

I instantiate a pathlib.Path object

```
p = pathlib.Path(file_path)
```

These both work fine as well:

```
open(p, 'r')
tensorflow.io.read_file(str(p))
```

But this does not work:

```
tensorflow.io.read_file(p)
```

it returns:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (PosixPath('/dir/sub_dir/my_image.jpg')) with an unsupported type (<class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>) to a Tensor.
```

Why is `tensorflow.io.read_file` not able to read `pathlib.Path` object

I understand why `tensorflow.io.read_file(str(p))` works fine. What I do not understand is that how is it `open` can work with path_like_object but `tensorflow.io.read_file` cannot

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Maybe TensorFlow is not using the open function directly on the read_file method. Gotta check out the source code and see what's under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

That's because tensorflow.io.read_file expects a String object as the file path, not a PosixPath object, which is what you're passing it from pathlib.

When you use str(path), you're converting the PosixPath to string, and thats why it works fine in that case.

You can find more details on the documentations.

TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file

PathLib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: I know why it works fine with str(path). What I do not understand is that how is it open can work with pathlib object but tf.io.read_file cannot

Comment: The open function works with what is known as "path-like object", which is literally any object that represents a file path in some way. That means it can work with a simple string, and also support more complex objects such as File Descriptors. Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open